# Change a text file to csv (multiple rows)

Tags: python, csv

I have a txt file that reads as:

```
interface 0/1
no data
no data
no data
no data
no data
interface 0/2
no data
etc...
```

I would like to have it output to a csv with a format of:

```
interface 0/1 | no data | no data | no data | no data | no data
interface 0/2 | no data | no data | no data | no data | no data
```

I have tried using the csv module and write row with no good results. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe what you have tried so far?

Comment: Are you sure you want that format for the output, because it's non-standard to have multi-character delimiters like `' | '` between values?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to group 6 lines into a row and write those, eg:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

with open('input.txt') as fin, open('output.csv', 'w') as fout:
    pipe_out = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='|')
    rows = iter(lambda: list(islice(fin, 6)), [])
    pipe_out.writerows(rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple, slightly different answer that uses python 2.7 only (no csv)

```
f=open("data.txt", 'r')  # original data
f1=open("output_data.txt", 'w')   # this is to write the output
newline=""
for line in f:
    if "interface" not in line:
        newline=newline + r" |  " + line.strip()
    else:
        # print newline # check this
        f1.write(newline + '\n')
        newline=line.strip()
# print newline # just a visual check
f1.write(newline)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try without the csv module:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
of = open("file.csv", "w")

data = f.readlines()
checkpoint = ""

for line in data:
    line = line.strip("\n")
    if "interface" in line:
        of.write(checkpoint + line)
        checkpoint = "\n"
    else:
        of.write(" | " + line)

f.close()
of.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

CSV module is usually not necessary.  This script will do just fine.

```
f1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('file2.csv', 'w+')

lines = f1.read()
for line in lines.split('\n'):
    if line == "":
        continue
    elif line.startswith("interface"):
        f2.write("\n"+line+",")
    else:
        f2.write(line+",")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done it like this:

```
content = ''
with open('text_file.txt', 'r') as txt_file:
  content = txt_file.read()

blocks = content.split('interface')

csv_content = ''
for block in blocks:
  if block != '':
    csv_content += 'interface %s\n' % ' | '.join(block.splitlines())

with open('csv_file.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
  csv_file.write(csv_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be by collecting a row's data from each line in the file and outputting it as a csv row whenever a line starting with `'interface'` is encountered:

```
import csv

input_filename = 'interface.txt'
output_filename = 'interface.csv'

with open(input_filename) as infile, \
     open(output_filename, 'w', newline='') as outfile:

    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='|')
    row = []

    for line in (line.rstrip() for line in infile):
        if not line.startswith('interface'):
            row.append(line)
        else:  # new group
            if row:
                writer.writerow(row)  # output last group
            row = [line]

    writer.writerow(row)  # output last row
```

Contents of `interface.csv` file afterwards:

```
interface 0/1|no data|no data|no data|no data|no data
interface 0/2|no data|no data|no data|no data|no data
```